# Calculate: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(3x)+f(5x)-2f(2x)}{x}$

Tags: derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

$f$ is a derivable function in $0$, and $f'(0)=a$

Calculate in terms of $a$:

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(3x)+f(5x)-2f(2x)}{x}$

Comment: The fact they give you the derivative should be a hint

Comment: @DougM: Your comment isn't right. Note that the numerator at $0$ is $2f(0)-2f(0)=0$. ... At any rate, L'Hôpital's not needed. Just use linear approximation directly: $f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x + \epsilon(x)$, where $\epsilon(x)/x\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @Frpzzd: the rule does not apply here as we don't know if $f'(x) $ exists in a neighborhood of $0$. We are only given that $f'(0)$ exists.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Blah, good point. :(

Answer (score 5):

Hint:
\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{f(3x)+f(5x)-2f(2x)}{x}\\
&=3\cdot\dfrac{f(3x)-f(0)}{3x}+5\cdot\dfrac{f(5x)-f(0)}{5x}-4\cdot\dfrac{f(2x)-f(0)}{2x}\\
&\rightarrow?
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Using a Maclauren series we can approximate $f(x)$ as $$f(x) = f(0)+x\cdot f'(0)+...$$
Since we will view x as small all the higher order terms can be ignored.
Plugging this into your equation we get
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(0)+ 3x \cdot f'(0)+f(0)+ 5x \cdot f'(0)-2\cdot f(0)- 2\cdot 2x \cdot f'(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{4ax}{x}=4a$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(k) = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{f(kx)-f(0)}{kx}\implies L = 3g(3)+5g(5)-2g(2)=3a+5a-2(2a)=4a$